# Parsing INI Configuration File with Java: Section Values Missing

Tags: java, ini

I'm working with an INI configuration file in Java and encountering issues with extracting values using both ini4j and IniEditor by Nik Haldimann. The structure of the configuration file is as follows:

```
ipv4=false
ipv6=false
ssu=false
ntcp2.enabled=false
ssu2.enabled=false
meshnets.yggdrasil=true
[sam]
## Enable the SAM bridge (default: true)
enabled = true
## Address and ports service will listen on (default: 127.0.0.1:7656, udp: 7655)
# address = 127.0.0.1
# port = 7656
# portudp = 7655
```

The problem I'm facing is that there are no section values such as 'root' or similar. I've attempted to retrieve values using standard methods and both mentioned libraries, but without success.

Could someone guide me on how to properly parse and edit this type of INI configuration file in Java? If there's a recommended library or a standard way to handle such configurations, I'd appreciate the advice.

I tried set "" section.

Comment: Please see the 
[How to Ask page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for help clarifying this question. Include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to 
reproduce the issue:  [how to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  Recommendations and opinion-based questions are [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions) for Stackoverflow.

Comment: [ini4j](https://techbuddy.dev/java-ini-file-handling-libraries-parsing-configuration) would be an option

Comment: ini4j give an error - Exception in thread "main" org.ini4j.InvalidFileFormatException: parse error (at line: 1): ipv4=false

Comment: Strange. I didn't get any errors with your file but it did designate the name of the first section with a question mark

Comment: https://github.com/PurpleI2P/i2pd-android/pull/66 
Apache common INI library are works perfect. 
org.apache.commons:commons-configuration2:2.3

Comment: Yes. As I mentioned, ini6j gave me *Section: ? .... Section: sam*